# php regular expression checking for name

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, string-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP regex to check a English name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623719/php-regex-to-check-a-english-name)

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will check a name field that i have for a user.

I want it to check for

```
Firstname SPACE Middle initial SPACE Last name.
```

I know for singular letters for the middle intitial I'll need `[a-z]` but I'm not sure how to do the full words for first and last name and the spaces in between.

Comment: Are all three parts required every time?

Comment: `[a-z]` won't match middle initials (since they are usually upper case!) not will it match any that have an accent.

Comment: Or what about [Regex get first name out of “Aardal, Prof.dr.ir. K.I. (Karen)”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351234/regex-get-first-name-out-of-aardal-prof-dr-ir-k-i-karen) -- Or what about [regex to parse first and last name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994870/regex-to-parse-first-and-last-name) -- And this seems similar as well: [How can I validate a name field to allow only one space, and begin and end with a letter in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118670/how-can-i-validate-a-name-field-to-allow-only-one-space-and-begin-and-end-with-a)

Comment: For the listing: [Regex for names with special characters (Unicode)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters-unicode/5963425#5963425) (hat tip Kristoffer la Cour +1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]\s[A-Za-z]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to make it a bit easier for your self.

Also, to check for names you might want to add more letters than just `a-z`, you should take a look at the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters-unicode/5963425#5963425).

Answer (score 1):

Name may contain `-` symbol. `/^[\-a-z]+\s[\-a-z]\s[\-a-z]+$/i`